# Print the prime numbers from 1 (where 1 is prime) to n with a function in JavaScript and append them to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, primes

I have a program, in which I have to print all prime numbers from 1 to n, and then append them to an array. I do this whit the solve function but the array remains empty. I want to ask why is that?

```
function solve(args){
    var m=new Array();
    for(let a=1;a<=args;a++){
        for(let b=1;b<=Math.sqrt(a);b++){
            if(a%b==0){
                break;
            }
            m.push(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: :)) All numbers are dividable to 1!!!
`...let b=1...`

Answer (score 2):

Check this snippet

```
solve(args) {
   var primeNumbers = [];
   for(var i=1; i<=args ;i++){
      var isPrime = true;
         for(var j=2; j<i; j++){
            if(i%j === 0){
                isPrime = false;
            }
         }
      if(isPrime === true){
         primeNumbers.push(i);
      }
   }
   console.log(primeNumbers);
}
```

Comment: 1 is not a prime number maybe try running the outer loop from 2 instead of 1

Comment: It depends on @Y.Ivanov choice whether or not take 1 as his wanted array collection. I just edited his code to give him what he wants. Please see his question title **Print the prime numbers from 1 (where 1 is prime) to n**

Comment: missed that. my bad

Answer (score 0):

Initialising array with 1 will solve this

```
solve(args) {
       var primeNumbers = [1];
       for(var i=1; i<=args ;i++){
          var isPrime = true;
             for(var j=2; j<i; j++){
                if(i%j === 0){
                    isPrime = false;
                }
             }
          if(isPrime === true){
             primeNumbers.push(i);
          }
       }
       console.log(primeNumbers);
    }
```

Comment: Why you need to hard code 1 ? If you putting 1 by default then why we will write a program for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the supplied number is greater than `2` and add `2` to your array. Then iterate from `3` to your supplied number, skipping all the even number by incrementing by `2`.

```js
function getPrimeNumber(num){
   let primeNumbers = [];
   
   if(num > 2)
    primeNumbers = [2];
    
   for(let a = 3; a <= num; a += 2){
    let isPrime = true;
       for(let b = 2; b <= Math.sqrt(a); b++){
        if(a%b == 0){
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
      }
      if(isPrime)
        primeNumbers.push(a);
   }
   
   return primeNumbers;
}

console.log(getPrimeNumber(100));
```

Answer (score 0):

Every number divided without reminder is a ***composite number***, hence no need to run modulo test on **all numbers** , but only on the subset of primary numbers lower than it.

```
 function solve(args){
        var primeNumbers = new Array();
            for(let a=2;a<=args;a++){
                // console.log("lets test: "+a);
                let isPrime = true;

                for(let prime of primeNumbers){
                    if(a % prime == 0){
                        // console.log(a +" is a composition of "+prime );
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(isPrime){
                    primeNumbers.push(a);
                }
      }
       return primeNumbers;
    }
```